# iBeacon identifier value -why its not working?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am getting data from and hardware iBeacon , in which i can program to change its UUID.

I know the `UUID` of the hardware, but i dont understand what is the identifier in :

```
[[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"com.name.iBeacon"];
```

Is it my app identifier, or something the iBeacon is transmitting(its name?) 
I wonder if this is why its not working .
I have set everything and i can't even discover the iBeacon :

```
 self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;

  NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"74278BDA-B644-4520-8F0C-720EAF059935"];
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"com.company.iBeacon"];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
      [self locationManager:self.locationManager didStartMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
```

Than these delegates, which are in the same class(should be in app delegate?) are never fired :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    NSLog(@"ENTER");

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    NSLog(@"EXIT");
}
```

I have read that you have to go in and out from the area ??

Another issue is, Apple says every BLE has services,that includes characteristic, but than, in iBeacon, what are the major and minor values? characteristics of the same service ?

Comment: The identifier is any string you want. You use it to distinguish between different beacon regions in your delegate methods. As to why your delegates aren't being called, if you are running ios8 you need to request when in use or always authorisation from location manager

Comment: The major and minor values are just ways of further identifying your region. Major might be a floor and minor might indicate the department - it is up to you. iBeacon is different to BLE devices - it doesn't advertise any services or characteristics

Comment: By the way, you wrong, the iBeacon does advertise services and characteristics, if you will write BLE code you will find it, and also its service . the service and characteristics are part of the protocol BLE

Comment: thnks about iOS8, i have added it, to get authorisation, but still nothing is moving, seems dead ..

Comment: The core bluetooth stack on ios filters the iBeacon advertisements. Many beacons advertise services and characteristics for configuration but this is not part of the iBeacon spec. They are vendor specific.

Answer (score 0):

Got it ,

```
 if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
```

Must be done first .